# Temporary Ban Command Issues

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make a temporary ban command for a discord bot that I am currently developing, and I keep running into an issue *(node:15340) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: ban is not defined* and I was trying to see if there is any guide or way to step so it can work, what I was trying to do is make when a command was executed it temporary bans someone and it displays the reason why in discord's audit log, also to send a embed saying who was the user banned by for what, so when someone would execute the command it would look like this - !ban (user) (time) (reason).

```
      let toBan = message.mentions.members.first();
      let reason = args.slice(2).join(" ");
      let member = message.guild.member(toBan)
      if(!args[0]) return  message.channel.send('Please mention some to ban, so I can ban that fooly!');
      if(!toBan)  return  message.channel.send(`${args[0]} is not a member of this guild, fooly.`);
      if(!reason)  return  message.channel.send('Please specify a reason for the ban fooly!');
      
      if(!toBan.bannable){
        return message.channel.send("This dude has super powers, fooly. I can't ban this person.")
      }

    if(member) {
        toBan.ban({
          reason: `${reason}`
        })
      }
        let bantime = args[1];
        if(!bantime) return message.reply("Fooly! You need to provide a time!");

        await(bantime(ban));
        message.reply(`Fooly has been banned for ${ms(ms(bantime))}`);

      if(toBan.bannable){
        const messageEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Fooly was banned')
        .addField('Person that was banned:', toBan)
        .addField('Banned by:', message.author)
        .addField('Reason:', reason)
        .setTimestamp(Date.now())
        .setColor('#FF0000')
        .setFooter('Fooly Discord Bot');
        message.channel.send(messageEmbed);
        toBan.ban();
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
          message.guild.members.unban(toBan)
          message.channel.send(`<@${toBan.id}> has been unbanned (temporary ban is finished).`);
        }, ms(bantime)); 
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So firstly, `bantime` is a string from the message and not a function, so that would return an error later on.
Secondly, `await(bantime(ban));` is giving you the error you specified, and it is exactly as it says. You do not have `ban` declared anywhere, thus it is unable to know what `ban` is referring to. You might be looking for

```js
let bantime = args[1];
if(!bantime) return message.reply("Fooly! You need to provide a time!");
message.reply(`Fooly has been banned for ${ms(ms(bantime))}`);
```

I just removed the `await(bantime(ban))` in the snippet above, I don't think there's a purpose for it after looking at your code.